# Query on Iot device

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, cloud, raspberry-pi2, iot

Can any one help me find a solution on this.

I would like to know whether there is any sensor that can sense and send data below -30°C. I came to know that arduino cant work on that temperature range.

I need to deploy something into a freezer like thing which can sense the -°C temperature and send it to the cloud or send it to some controller(wire less) near by and that controller will send the data to raspberry-pi or cloud.

Thank you for the valuable commands.

Answer (score 0):

- Temperature range depends on used sensor (some sensors can measure temperatures from -200°C).
- Temperature range for other electronic is not so good.
  Basically you can use internally heated encapsulation, but it is not suitable for battery application.
  Or you can place inside only the sensor and rest of circuit will be outside.

Comment: Thank you friend.                                                                                                             Yes I just want to place the sensor inside the unit, and the rest outside. But how can I send that sensed data to the controlling unit using wireless method. I don't find any solution for this.